# unable to scrape the search content from Amazon

Tags: php, php-curl

```
<?php

$curl=curl_init();
$string_name="php books";
$url="https://www.amazon.in/s/field-keywords=$string_name";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

> Blockquote

From the above code I am trying to curl "php books" from amazon website yet 
    it showing "Unable to connect using required security protocol. To access the page requested, please 
    upgrade or use a different browser or mobile device to ensure that your experience on Amazon will be 
    uninterrupted." - Any idea to get rid-off this issue.

[image: Amazon error page]

Comment: It is most likely due to the scarcity of configuration options in the curl request. I'd suggest you use the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to help with the SSL connection, add `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` too and also `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`

Comment: Why are you trying to scrape Amazon’s content in the first place? Do you not think it’ll be protected by copyright…?

Answer (score 0):

Using the options I mentioned in the comment ( and a few more ) this useful `curl` function ought to help resolve the issue. If you need to override the default options simply include them in the `$options` array parameter with a different value. Similarly you can add custom headers should you wish.

```
<?php

    function curl( $url=NULL, $options=NULL, $headers=false ){
        /*
            Download a copy of `cacert.pem` from here
            https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

            copy to webserver somewhere and modify below path
            to suit your environment
        */  
        $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';
        $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');


        session_write_close();

        /* Initialise curl request object */
        $curl=curl_init();
        if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
        }
        /* Define standard options */
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );
        /* Assign runtime parameters as options */
        if( isset( $options ) && is_array( $options ) ){
            foreach( $options as $param => $value ) curl_setopt( $curl, $param, $value );
        }
        if( $headers && is_array( $headers ) ){
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        }
        /* Execute the request and store responses */
        $res=(object)array(
            'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
            'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
            'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
        );
        rewind( $vbh );
        $res->verbose=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
        fclose( $vbh );
        curl_close( $curl );
        return $res;
    }

    $keyword='books';
    $baseurl='https://www.amazon.in/s/field-keywords';

    $url=sprintf('%s=%s',$baseurl,$keyword);
    $res=curl( $url );
    if( $res->info->http_code==200 ){
        echo $res->response;
    }
?>
```